# How to show Laravel form validation error as a 'warning' but still be able to pass the validation?

Tags: php, laravel, validation, laravel-9

I have created a custom validation rule using `php artisan make:rule ResultValidator`  and used it to check if the value lies within the `reference_min` and `reference_max` of the `tests` table.

**This shows the error message properly. However, I want to show the message just as warning and still be able to pass the validation. Is it possible to do it that way? If not what could be the alternative?**
[image]

ResultValidator.php

```php
<?php

namespace App\Rules;

use App\Models\Test;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;

class ResultValidator implements Rule
{
    /**
     * Create a new rule instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Determine if the validation rule passes.
     *
     * @param  string  $attribute
     * @param  mixed  $value
     * @return bool
     */
    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $test =  Test::where('test_name', $attribute)->get()->first();
        return $value  >  $test->reference_min && $value <  $test->reference_max;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation error message.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function message()
    {
        return 'Warning : The value does not lie on the normal range.';
    }
}
```

Controller's store() method:

```php
    public function store( Request $request){
     $request->validate([
            'blood_glucose_f' => ['required', new ResultValidator() ],
        ]);
     Report::create($request);
    }
```

Blade :

```html
 <x-auth-validation-errors class="text-danger mb-4" :errors="$errors" />

 <form method="POST" action="/test-orders/enter-result">
    @csrf
     <div  class="mb-3">
          <label    for="blood_glucose_f" class="form-label"> Blood Glucose F </label>
          <x-input   id="blood_glucose_f" class="form-control form-control-lg"
           type="number" name="blood_glucose_f"
           :value="old('blood_glucose_f')"   />
     </div> ...
```

Comment: Laravel Validation logic is only aware of 2 cases; "Pass" (true), or "Fail" (false). If you want to support another "level", you'll need use some kind of custom implementation.

Comment: In the `passes` method, you may flush (store) the error message to the session and show that message on the next page load (if the other rules were fulfilled) and you should return `ture` (from `passes` method) whenever you think a warning should be emitted while allowing the the validation to pass.

Comment: @SajalKuikel You're welcome! Glad I managed to help you.